# remove selectedRow in handsontable using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui, handsontable

I have an handsontable like the below image. After selecting any one of the rows (for example `LastName`) it should remove that particular row permanently. How can I achieve this using jQuery?

[image]

This is my code which I have written using the `afterSelection` function but I don't know how to delete that row.

```js
this.tab.handsontable({
  data: self.data,
  dataSchema: {
    columnsexpo: null,
    placeholder: null
  },
  colHeaders: ['Columns Export'],
  rowHeaders: true,
  fixedColumns: true,
  fillHandle: {

    autoInsertRow: false,
  },
  columnSorting: true,
  columns: [{
    data: 'columnsexpo',
    readOnly: true
  }, ],
  stretchH: 'all',
  className: "htCenter",
  height: 420,
  afterChange: function() {},
  beforeRemoveRow: function(row, col) {
    var m = this.getDataAtCell(row, 0);
    var mandatory = true;
    self.MandatoryFields.forEach(function(item) {
      if (!_.isEmpty(m)) {
        var found = m.toLowerCase().includes(item.toLowerCase());
        if (found) {
          mandatory = false;
        }
      }
    });
    if (!mandatory) {
      return false
    } else
      return true;
  },
  afterSelection: function(r, c) {
    var da = this.getDataAtRow(r);
    selectedRow = "";
    selectedRow = da[0];
    console.log(selectedRow);
  },
  afterRender: function() {
    if (init) {
      Events.trigger("DEW:ValidRequest", 1, self.checkValid());
    }
    init = true;
    $('#tablesortable thead th div').filter(function() {
      return $(this).text() == "Columns Export";
    }).popup({
      title: 'Columns Export',
      position: 'top center'
    });
  }
});
```

**EDIT**

```
afterSelection: function(r,c,e){

            var dat = this.getDataAtRow(r)

            this.alter('remove_row', r, 1);
            console.log(r);

          },
```

> Now after applying above function it is removing selected Row but if i select last row it is removing all previously selected row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `hot.alter('remove_row', 10, 2);`  inside after selection method of handsontable.

No need for jquery.

Or if you want to use jquery, store the handsontable instance in some varitable and call the same on row selection.

Update -- added deselectCell before removing the row. after removing the row, previous row is getting selected which is causing the problem.

```
afterSelection: function(r, c, e) {
    this.deselectCell()
    this.alter('remove_row', r, 1);
  }
```

Comment: if i use this function it will remove last 2 row what if i want to remove some row which is in middle

Comment: You want to remove row which is selected, do some checking on selection and remove the row. Pass correct parameters and you can remove any row(s)

Comment: Now i am removing the selected row but i have one small issue if i remove last row it is removing all previous selected rows